# i have two table called users and stock_transfer_cnf_ord i want to join and fetch data where role = courier

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT stock_transfer_cnf_ord.order_id, stock_transfer_cnf_ord.retailer_user_name, stock_transfer_cnf_ord.boy_user_name, stock_transfer_cnf_ord.order_status, stock_transfer_cnf_ord.order_on, users.address
FROM stock_transfer_cnf_ord JOIN
     users
     ON stock_transfer_cnf_ord.boy_user_name = 'manish' and role='courier'
```

when i run this query i get repeated data. actually i want the address from user where role is retailer

[image]

> here is my two table users and stock_transfer_cnf_ord

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Data as *text* tables is much preferred over fuzzy images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `JOIN` condition between the tables:

```
SELECT st.order_id, st.retailer_user_name, stock_transfer_cnf_ord.boy_user_name, st.order_status, st.order_on, u.address
FROM stock_transfer_cnf_ord st JOIN
     users u
     ON st.boy_username = u.username
--------^ the join condition references both tables
WHERE st.boy_user_name = 'manish' and u.role = 'retailer';
```

I also added table aliases -- they make the query easier to write and to read.